# What's the difference between Rail's AssetTagHelper and Scott Becker's AssetPackager?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to compress all my js and css files for a project and bundle into one file (one js and one css file). Which one do you recommend for a Rails 3.0 out of http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html and http://synthesis.sbecker.net/pages/asset_packager and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend using Jammit from DocumentCloud (if you don't know DocumentCloud, they are behind some very good open source projects like Underscore.js, Backbone.js...) :

http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/

See the docs for the features, it's very powerful...

Comment: Thanks @slainer68, I'll check it out. However, I still don't understand what the difference between using Jammit or AssetPackager and the default AssetTagHelper.

Comment: AssetTagHelper is just a module which contains some helpers like javascript_include_tag, stylesheet_link_tag, etc... None of these helpers will help you compress all your JS/CSS in ONE file. For this kind of thing, you should use a packager like Jammit. Fine?

Comment: Look at the "Caching multiple javascripts into one" section here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html It does combine several js files into one.